# Used Excel VBA/Selenium, created Insta follow bot, I think it will be caught by Insta after first 50 followings, any remarks, for learning purposes?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver, bots, instagram

The following script is a daily script that follows 400 people per day in a span of 8 hours or so. It is stopped in order to prevent the browser window from closing after it is finished running, allowing the user to reset the script from the first stop manually the next day. This is done in order to continue the script if the computer is put to sleep overnight or is left on for the next day to begin.

[I've made it this far...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc2cK.png)

Edit: Script Completed

sub completed

Edit: Violation of Instagram Terms and Conditions. You aren't supposed to be doing this with Instagram. Supposed to is a very strong way of saying that you shouldn't but probably will. This you still interested in this kind of developing. That you get a selenium script to automatically log into Instagram without being caught. Though to become a part of a group then you have taken the time to read this please leave a comment below. It's supposed to not make sense but you have taken the time to completely read this and that not an act for punishment. It is always about reading into the sub scripts and small places. Instagram takes offense to violators of it's terms and services. If you try to violate these terms and conditions you can be caught. Those who are caught will be punished by their rules.

End Sub

This is the way that you Are going to get caught doing something with Instagram. That is the only thing you are doing that you Can get caught. Though you might Want to do so then you will be caught.

Hide in plain sight.

Comment: That sounds like something that would violates the terms for instagram.

Comment: I think you are right, any suggestions, for learning purposes?